# Standard error of estimated marginal means with unequal variance assumption

Tags: r

I've run a repeated measure anova and got at the point where I have to calculate the estimated marginal means. I have two versions of the same dataset but for this purpose I'm using the long format one. Here is my code:

```
df <- data.frame(Time = c(rep("E1", 20), rep("E2", 20), rep("E3", 20), rep("E4", 20)),
           Extension = c(60, 52, 56, 52, 68, 80, 84, 64, 72, 56, 52, 64, 68, 64, 60, 76, 80, 76, 68, 64, 68, 60, 64, 60, 68, 80, 88, 68, 76, 60, 60, 72, 76, 72, 60, 80, 80, 80, 80, 68, 68, 68, 72, 72, 72, 80, 88, 72, 88, 68, 68, 76, 84, 80, 68, 84, 84, 80, 80, 68, 68, 76, 73, 85, 74, 82, 86, 71, 86, 71, 69, 78, 88, 85, 79, 86, 87, 85, 80, 81),
           Extension_fct = as.factor(c(rep("E1", 20), rep("E2", 20), rep("E3", 20), rep("E4", 20))))

mod <- lm(Extension ~ Extension_fct, data = df)
emmeans::emmeans(mod, pairwise ~ Extension_fct)
```

The problem is that the model I'm using assume the equal variance, and therefore all the standard errors across the four levels are the same. Is it possible to adjust it in order to get separated standard errors? If not, how can I calculate them by hand?

Comment: Yes -- fit a different model. See the FAQs vignette, last section. emmeans does not analyze the data, it analyzes the model you chose.

Comment: I would like to know exactly what model to fit to get a separated calculation for each level.